# Import RSS Feed to a specific taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, feeds

I want to use Feeds (and maybe Feeds Tamper??) to import some RSS feeds.

I want to add a taxonomy to my feeds.

Example : Yahoo Business RSS is tagged with "Business" taxonomy term.
Yahoo News RSS is tagged with "News" taxonomy term.
Reuters News RSS is tagged with "news" taxonomy term.
etc...

How can I add a taxonomy term to my feed import form ?

Thank you,

Comment: I want to do something like http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/build-aggregation-site-drupal-part-1 but "Step 3: Set up a vocabulary" doesn't exist in D7 ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the feeds module you should have a content type set up in which you'll import these items.  I believe the tutorial is just saying that you should set up this new vocabulary and then add a term reference to it in your new content type.

In Drupal 7, to make sure you can set up your vocabulary, verify the following

1. When you go to /admin/modules on your site, is the **Taxonomy** module enabled?  If not, check it and save the page
2. Once that's done, you should be able to go to admin/structure/taxonomy to add your new vocabulary.

Don't forget that you should then add a term_reference field in your content type, so you can tag it with those new terms...

Hope that makes sense!  Let us know if it worked.

Comment: It works, thank you !

Now I must find how users can easily do it themself. Maybe a personalized submit form, but it' another problem... 

Thank you again for your help.